# integrate video in iphone app

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have to integrate a video into my iphone app.The difference from all the code that there is on the net is that I have to show the video and give to the user the chance to play it.Not to play it automatically.

And here is what I have done:

```
- (void) play
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileUrl1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    videoPlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileUrl1];
    [videoPlayer1 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [[videoPlayer1 view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    //[videoPlayer1 play];
    [self.view addSubview:[videoPlayer1 view]];    
}
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)_notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [videoPlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];
    [videoPlayer1 stop];
    [videoPlayer1 release];
    videoPlayer1 = nil;
}
```

But the screen just turn black and nothing else shown.

Unless I do `[videoPlayer1 play]` nothing happens.But I don't want to play the video automatically...it must be played by the user.
So, how should I act in order to show up the video(!not the black screen) and play it when the user wishes?Thanks

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable in this, but could it be that the first frame of the video is completely black? Or, perhaps iOS is doing something equivalent?

Comment: you could be right.Any idea how to change the frame that the video shows up before been played, because now I can't even see a play button:)

Comment: not a clue, sorry, I've never done iOS development - it was just a guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an error and here it is

Change this

[videoPlayer1 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

to

[videoPlayer1 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

You are hiding the controls by using that line of yours.

Cheers!!!